# Webpack load fonts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have this code in a React element:

```
require('../../Style/fonts/SomethingStrange.ttf')
```

In my Webpack.config:

```
{ test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/, 
      loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]' }
```

Problem: no font on my webpages...

Doesn't Webpack let me automatically require fonts? Do I have to program anything else to load fonts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to require your fonts inside css files, not inside js/jsx files. For example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SomethingStrange';
    src: url('../../Style/fonts/SomethingStrange.ttf');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Was a little bit confused with requiring the css in js/jsx.

Comment: You can also use webpack's `fontgen-loader` for automatically generating webfont packs.